# Using linear least-squares to solve this system

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-regression, weighted-least-squares

I have $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ equations of the form:

$$2(x_j-x_i)X+2(y_j-y_i)Y+2(z_j-z_i)Z+2v^2\tau(t_i-t_j)=2v^2(t_i^2-t_j^2)+(x_j^2+y_j^2+z_j^2)-(x_i^2+y_i^2+z_i^2)$$

With $n\geq 4$, and where everything except $X,Y,Z$ and $\tau$ are known

I understand that this equation (actually, $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ equations/datapoints) can be solved for $X,Y,Z,\tau$ (values which I'll use as initial estimates for a more ``precise" solver) with a linear least-squares fit. How, in practice, is this done? I know not too much about the topic. Would I want a multivariate least-squares fit? A multiple least-squares fit? "Standard" least-squares?

My recollection is that I'd wan't a multiple least-squares fit, however I'm not sure.

Note that I specifically want to use least-squares here, and the goal is to obtain estimates for $X,Y,Z,\tau$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your equations are of the form

$Xv_1+Yv_2+Zv_3+\tau v_4 = b$

where $v_1,v_2,v_3, v_4$ and $b$ are vectors. Write A = {the matrix whose columns are $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$} then the 4 vector $w$ of numbers you want is the solution of the normal equation

$A^TAw = A^Tb$

which is your least squares solution.

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you, perhaps, elaborate on *why* this describes the solution (it isn't immediately obvious to me why this works but, then again, this isn't a topic which I'm very familiar with).

Comment: The lhs is also $Ax$ where $x$ is column vector $(X, Y, Z, \tau )$. You want to try and write $b$ as a sum of the 4 vectors on the left. This is impossible as the eqns are inconsistent. Let $Aw$ be the closet combination to $b$. Then $Aw-b$ is orthogonal to the space spanned by the 4 vectors i.e the columns of A. These are the rows of $A^T$, the transpose of A, and the orthogonality can be expressed as $A^T(Aw - b) = 0$. With 2 vectors and 2 unknows this process gives the familiar regression line through a set of points.

Comment: Since $Aw$ is the closest possible point to b it minimizes the squared distance ${{\left\| Aw-b \right\|}^{2}}$ , hence the name least squares.