# Why does $A^TAw = A^Tb$ describe the least square solution to a multivariate system?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-regression

Note that this builds off a previous question, found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947921/using-linear-least-squares-to-solve-this-system).

Suppose I have a system of equations of the form:

$$Wv_1 + Xv_2 + Yv_3 + Zv_4 = b$$

Where $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$, and $b$ are vectors. I want to determine the least squares solution for unknowns $W,X,Y,Z$. As I understand it, the solutions are the vector $w$ in:

$$A^{T}Aw = A^{T}b$$

Where $A$ is the matrix who's columns are $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$.

It isn't clear to me, however, why this is. Why is $w$ the least-squares solution, mathematically and intuitively? I've tried to do some research online, however I haven't found much (and what I have found uses extensively terminology with which I'm unfamiliar— unfortunately, this isn't a subject I'm particularly familiar with).

Comment: Is your question about the existence of $w$ in general?

Comment: @GAUSS1860 With the end goal of determining (at least, estimating) $W,X,Y,Z$, it isn't clear to me why the vector $w$ holds the least-square solutions (or, moreover, how to find $w$, in practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A\in\mathbb{R^{m\times n}}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R^{m}}$ The least squares problem defined as seeking $x\in\mathbb{R^{n}}$ so that $\|b-A x\|_{2}=\min _{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}\|b-A y\|_{2}$ is equivalent to minimizing the function $\Phi(x)=\|b-A x\|_{2}^{2}$ over $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such
that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi(.) &: \quad \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+} \cup\{0\} \\
\Phi(x) &=\|b-A x\|_{2}^{2}=(b-A x)^{T}(b-A x)=b^{T} b-b^{T}(A x)-(A x)^{T} b+(A x)^{T}(A x) \\
&=\|b\|_{2}^{2}-2(A x)^{T} b+x^{T} A^{T} A x \\
&=\|b\|_{2}^{2}+2 \Psi(x)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are given. Thus $,\|b\|_{2}^{2}$ is a constant and minimizing $\Phi(x)$ is equivalent to minimizing
$$
\Psi(x)-\frac{1}{2} x^{T} A^{T} A x-x^{T} A^{T} b
$$
To prove this equivalence, we note that : \begin{aligned}
\Psi(x) &=& \frac{1}{2}(A x)^{T}(A x)-x^{T}\left(A^{T} b\right)=\frac{1}{2} y^{T} y-x^{T} c & & \text { where } y=A x \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{m} y_{i}^{2}-\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{j} x_{j} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} A(i, j) x_{j}\right)^{2}-\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{j} x_{j} & & \text { since } y_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} A(i, j) x_{j}
\end{aligned}
Thus, $\Psi(x)=\Psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots, x_{n}\right)$ is a quadratic function of the unknowns $x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots, x_{n} .$ To find the minimum of $\Psi(x)$
it should be such that :
$$
\nabla \Psi(x)=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x_{1}}(x) \\
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x_{2}}(x) \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x_{n}}(x)
\end{array}\right]=0 $$ $$ \begin{aligned}
\Longleftrightarrow\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x_{k}}(x) &=\sum_{i=1}^{m} A(i, k)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} A(i, j) x_{j}\right)-c_{k}=0, \quad \text { for } \quad k=1,2, \cdots, n \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{m} A(i, k)(A(i,:) x)-c_{k}=0 \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{m} A^{T}(k, i) y_{i}-c_{k}=0 \\
&=A^{T}(k,:) y-c_{k}=0
\end{aligned} $$

$$
$$

$$
\therefore\left\{\begin{array}{l}
A^{T}(1,:) y=c_{1} \\
A^{T}(2,:) y=c_{2} \\
\vdots \\
A^{T}(n,:) y=c_{n}
\end{array} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad A^{T} y=c \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad A^{T} A x=A^{T} b\right.$$

Now likewise, We will show that if $x$ solves the normalized system $A^{T} A x=A^{T} b,$ then it solves the Least squares problem.
For any $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Psi(x)-\Psi(y) &=\frac{1}{2} x^{T} A^{T} A x-x^{T}\left(A^{T} b\right)-\frac{1}{2} y^{T} A^{T} A y+y^{T}\left(A^{T} b\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2} x^{T} A^{T} A x-x^{T}\left(A^{T} A x\right)-\frac{1}{2} y^{T} A^{T} A y+y^{T}\left(A^{T} A x\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{2} x^{T} A^{T} A x-\frac{1}{2} y^{T} A^{T} A y+y^{T} A^{T} A x \\
&=-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)^{T} A^{T} A(x-y) \\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\|A(x-y)\|_{2}^{2} \leqslant 0 \\
\therefore \Psi(x) & \leqslant \Psi(y) \quad \text { for any } y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus the existence of solution/s to the least squares problem reduces to studying the existence of solution/s to the
system
$$
A^{T} A x=A^{T} b
$$
where $G=A^{T} A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric positive semi-definite and $\operatorname{rank}\left(A^{T} A\right)=\operatorname{rank}(A)=r \leqslant \min (m, n)$

Answer (score 0):

If you have $Ax =b$ then the least squares solution can be taken from the *normal equations* which are given by multiplying by the transpose on each side. This makes a square matrix.

$$ A^TAx = A^Tb$$

Now the least squares problem is

$$ f(x) =  \|  b - Ax \|_{2}^{2} = (b-Ax)^T (b-Ax) = b^Tb - x^TA^Tb - b^TAx  + x^TA^TAx$$

this comes from how $\| \cdot \|$ works. $ b - Ax = r$ which is the residual and $\| r \|_{2}^{2} = rr^{T}$ so they are attempting to minimize the residual. You can distribute $(b-Ax)^T(b-Ax)$ and you'll get that above.

How is it achieved? If $f(x)$ is a global minimum then $ \nabla f(x) = 0$ and

$$ \nabla (x^TA^Tb) = A^Tb \\ \nabla(b^TAx) = A^Tb \\ \nabla (x^TA^TAx) = 2A^TAx$$

which gives us
$$ \nabla f(x) = 2A^TAx -  2A^Tb$$

so we solve that for 0